# Delete [pedantic] tag

Tags: support, tags

The user [Thursagen](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/8183/thursagen), which is suspended for three years (!), added the tag [pedantic](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pedantic) to several posts.  An exhaustive check of the revision histories of all questions with this tag indicates that no other user had added this tag to any question.  It appears that Thursagen was trolling by adding this tag to these questions.  As this is an abuse of the tagging system, can a moderator "burninate" it?

Comment: Three years for adding the tags pedantic seems pretty excessive. Is it that *bad*? Even hardened criminals are granted parole.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am not a mod, but I manually edited all of the questions to remove that tag. It's gone now.

Comment: I didn't check but were those unreasonable uses of 'pedantic'?

Comment: @Mitch, pretty much. They didn't add anything to the question, and in any case [pedantic] is a meta-tag, which is discouraged across SE.

Comment: Thank you! Both of you, JS for implementing and @DragonLord for asking initially. If I thought a question I asked had the possibility of being tagged as [pedantic], I would not ask any, ever. I'd rather get down voted, or closed, than tagged [pedantic].

Comment: @FeralOink, "I'm not pompous, I'm pedantic. There's a difference. Let me explain it to you."